# How do I use an IF-THEN or Condition Statement for Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

What would the condition statement be if I wanted all my sold items to go red in column F, but leave the ones un-shaded that have the word "Received" also in column F? The Headings of my Excel sheet are as follows;

Item-Paid-Worth Today-Parts Needed-Worth Retail-Sold-Profit-Profit as %
Mustang in Blue      Paid $0    Worth $80.00        Retail $140.00  Sold For $50.00     Profit= $50.00  Profit as % is 5000.

Comment: need more info, how about some actual sample data

Comment: Add Conditional Formatting on the cell/column/row that you want to go red. The rule is flexible enough to evaluate the cell/column/row and present each cell as desired.

Comment: Headings are as follows;

Comment: Item-Paid- Worth Today -Parts Needed- Worth Retail- Sold-Profit- and  Profit as %.
Ex. Mustang   $-     $80.00    $140.00   $50.00   $50.00  5000%

Comment: @user449330: Edit the question instead of including important information in comments, which might get hidden or deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. I removed the second question so it doesn't gain answers not related to the title of your post. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!